# How to populate a form field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've the following jQuery that I've used which allows you to click anywhere within an image (which is a picture of a map) and when you click, it places a marker on the map:-

```
<img src="images/marker.png" id="marker" style="display: none; position: absolute;" />
<img src="images/square.png" id="map"/>

$('#map').click(function(e)
{
   $('#marker').css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY).show();
   // Position of the marker is now e.pageX, e.pageY 
   // ... which corresponds to where the click was.
 });
```

The idea is that when you've clicked on the map, a co-ordinate is populated into a form field so you can submit the form with that information of where you clicked.

What do I need to change within my jQuery to add this functionality? Also, will this work accurately within IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden input for form fields to save co-ordinates. Please see below code :

Assuming xValue and yValue are your form fields, then create two hidden inputs inside form tag like :

```
<form action="...">
    <input type="hidden" id="xValue" name="xValue">
    <input type="hidden" id="yValue" name="yValue">
</form>
```

Modify your jQuery like :

```
$('#map').click(function(e)
{
   $('#marker').css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY).show();
   // Position of the marker is now e.pageX, e.pageY 
   // ... which corresponds to where the click was.

   $('#xValue').val(e.pageX);
   $('#yValue').val(e.pageY);
 });
```

And when you submit form, you can read xValue and yValue.

Comment: Thank you, that's great. Will this work in IE ok to get the mouse position of the marker?

I've seen this code somewhere else on Stack Overflow with regards to it or would my code work ok as it is?

var isIE = document.all?true:false;
document.onmousemove = getMousePosition;
function getMousePosition(e) {
  var _x;
  var _y;
  if (!isIE) {
    _x = e.pageX;
    _y = e.pageY;
  }
  if (isIE) {
    _x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    _y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
  }

posX = _x-5;
posY = _y-5;

  return true;
}

Comment: yes it should work. It is just event object from which you are reading x and y co-ordinate, so it should work in any browser.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<img src="images/marker.png" id="marker" style="display: none; position: absolute;" />
<img src="images/square.png" id="map"/>
<form action="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="coord[x]" id="coordX" />
    <input type="hidden" name="coord[y]" id="coordY" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

$('#map').click(function(e)
{
    $('#marker').css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY).show();
    $('#coordX').val(e.pageX);
    $('#coordY').val(e.pageY);
});
```